# Есть ли какая-то связь между переменными среды Windows и словарём os.environ в Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv, environment-variables

Я выяснил, что добавление в список переменных среды для пользователя и для системы не влияет на словарь os.environ. Однако часто, когда я гуглил информацию по environ, находил, что называются они точно так же, как и этот же раздел в Windows. Тогда как можно влиять на os.environ вне запускаемого скрипта, чтобы там сходу лежала нужная мне пара ключ-значение? Верно ли я предполагаю, что это делается через виртуальное окружение?

Comment: «Я выяснил» — как выясняли? Перезагружаться после изменений не забывали?

Comment: Оу, перезагружаться? Я об этом не подумал. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. Нигде в интернете перезагрузка не отмечалась. Не знаю, как поступать в таком случае с вопросом. Вы могли бы ответить на него, наверное.

Comment: @PaveTranquil дело не в перезагрузке, нужно всего лишь перезапустить скрипт, в документации на этот счет указано что переменая os.environ инициализируется один раз в момент импорта модуля os, в случае внешнего изменения или внутреннего через  putenv()  все равно нужно модифицировать os.environ вручную (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

Comment: И это работает с любыми программами. Консоль тоже нужно перезапускать.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в этом-то и дело, что перезапуска скрипта мало. Я даже запустил отдельно интерпретатор, импортировал os и проверил содержание environ — ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @КириллМалышев значит в windows обновление происходит после перезагрузки

Comment: @КириллМалышев, спасибо, действительно сработало. Перезапуска скрипта мало, перезапуска ПК много, а вот перезапуск консоли в самый раз.